# Automatically add <!--nextpage--> after X number of paragraphs

Tags: wp-link-pages, quicktag

Is it possible to automatically add the `<!--nextpage-->` quicktag after X number of paragraphs?

My client isn't exactly tech savvy so I'm trying to find a way to help them break up their enormous pages without them having to come back to me time and time again asking how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The concept

Adding something to the content during saving and considering all sorts of possible MarkUp isn't an easy task. I played around a bit with it and decided that the best chance would be to use PHP native `\DOMDocument` class to parse the content, identify the paragraph and add the HTML comment to it. This is much more reliable than using Regular Expressions and much better performance wise.

### Adjusting the plugin

First, the plugin uses *Dependency Injection* to decouple the classes. If you need to alter the output (change the number of paragraphs, insert some other comment like a line break or something from a shortcode, etc.), you'll need to jump in and adjust the arguments for the `Parser` class that is initialized from inside the `Controller`.

If you want to insert some normal HTML (for example an ad after the X paragraph), then you'll need to go into the `Parser` and remove the following line:

```
$comment = $this->dom->appendChild( new \DOMComment( $this->tag ) );
```

and then replace the `$comment` in the next line with `$this->tag`. Then you can throw in normal HTML tags, text or whatever.

For more complicated stuff, you'll need to utilize the `DOMDocument` and similar object methods. Please refer to php.net for further information.

### Notes

The following plugin only works with PHP 5.3+. If you got an earlier version, it simply won't activate and instead show you a WP die screen.

### The plugin

```
<?php
namespace WPSE\NextpageParagraph107787;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#107787) Nextpage after X paragraphs
 * Plugin URl:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107787
 * Description: <strong>Needs PHP 5.3+!</strong> Adds a <code><!--nextpage--></code> tag after X paragraphs.
 * Author:      Franz Josef Kaiser
 * Author URl:  http://unserkaiser.com
 * License:     MIT
 */

\add_action( 'init', array( __NAMESPACE__.'\Controller', 'init' ) );
class Controller
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    public static function init()
    {
        null === self::$instance AND self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $parser = new Parser();
        $parser->setTag( 'nextpage' );
        $parser->setTagAmount( 5 );

        \add_action( 'load-post.php', array( $parser, 'onSave' ) );
        \add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( $parser, 'onSave' ) );
    }
}

class Parser
{
    private $dom    = null;
    private $tag    = null;
    private $amount = null;

    public function __construct( $tag = null, $paragraph_number = null )
    {
        null === $this->dom
            AND $this->dom = new \DOMDocument();
    }

    public function setTag( $tag )
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }

    public function setTagAmount( $amount )
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function onSave( $post_id )
    {
        if ( empty( $_POST['content'] ) )
            return;

        $this->dom->loadHTML( \wpautop( $_POST['content'] ) );
        $paragraph = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName( 'p' );

        $content = null;
        $i = 1;
        foreach ( $paragraph as $p )
        {
            $content .= $this->dom->saveHTML( $p );
            if (
                $this->amount === $i++
                AND $this->amount < $paragraph->length
                )
            {
                $comment = $this->dom->appendChild( new \DOMComment( $this->tag ) );
                $content .= $this->dom->saveHTML( $comment );
            }
        }

        // Add to the HTTP $_POST global
        $_POST['content'] = $content;
    }
}

\register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( __NAMESPACE__.'\Setup', 'onActivation' ) );    
\register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( __NAMESPACE__.'\Setup', 'onDeactivation' ) );    
\register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( __NAMESPACE__.'\Setup', 'onUninstall' ) );
class Setup
{
    public function onActivation()
    {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
            return;
        $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
        check_admin_referer( "activate-plugin_{$plugin}" );

        // do stuff
    }

    public function onDeactivation()
    {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
            return;
        $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
        check_admin_referer( "deactivate-plugin_{$plugin}" );

        // do stuff
    }

    public function onUninstall()
    {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
            return;
        check_admin_referer( 'bulk-plugins' );

        if ( __FILE__ != WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN )
            return;

        // do stuff
    }
}
```